# Remove html tags and if shows bullet list then it not display bullets in previous gridview columns

Tags: c#, html, sql, asp.net, .net

I can use text area for saving the details of form. When I set the bullet list then bullets can be displayed in the previous cell in gridview. the following design for gridview row of Description column is:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description" sortExpression="description" >
  <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Literal ID="Description" runat="server" Text='<%# 
   System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Eval("description").ToString()) %>'> 
   </asp:Literal>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And the code for aspx.cs page is:

```
protected void ONCETASKGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Label newlabel = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("SubjectLabel");
        e.Row.Cells[6].ToolTip = Regex.Replace((e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView)["handover_subject"].ToString(), @"<(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty);
        e.Row.Cells[2].ToolTip = Regex.Replace((e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView)["msp_name"].ToString(), @"<(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty);
        e.Row.Cells[3].ToolTip = Regex.Replace((e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView)["priority_name"].ToString(), @"<(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty);
        e.Row.Cells[4].ToolTip = Regex.Replace((e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView)["c_cat_name"].ToString(), @"<(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty);
        //e.Row.Cells[7].ToolTip = Regex.Replace((e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView)["description"].ToString(), @"<(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty);

        Button completeB = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("ONCETASK_DELETE_Button");
        Label completeL = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("ONCETASK_DELETE_Label");
        string select_query = "SELECT hide FROM tbl_schedule_task_list WHERE hide=0 AND schedule_id=" + ONCETASKGridView.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString();
        SqlCommand select_cmd = new SqlCommand(select_query, con);
        con.ConnectionString = constr;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = select_cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                if (Session["role"].ToString().Equals("2") || Session["desig"].ToString().Equals("16"))
                {
                    completeB.Visible = true;
                    completeL.Visible = false;

                }
                else
                {
                    completeL.Visible = true;
                    completeB.Visible = false;
                }
                con.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                completeL.Text = "Deleted";
                completeB.Visible = false;
                completeL.Visible = true;
                completeL.CssClass = "error";
                con.Close();
                reader.Close();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception er)
        {
            ERRORPopUpLabel.Text = "Error While Binding AD_HOC Grid.Please Concern Your DEVELOPER";
            ERRORPanel.Visible = true;
            ERRORModalPopupExtender.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

So I want to remove the bullets or its display in only particular column in grid. The output is in following images:
[image]

Comment: Please provide the data that you are fetching for "description". run the query in sql and post your result here. that data seems to be responsible for bullets

Comment: This code is vulnerable to sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS set to the `UL` element has probably been set to zero padding somewhere. So you need to re-apply that again.

```
<style>
    td ul {
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
    }
</style>
```